# How get property value with reflection in C#

Tags: c#, reflection

I have a date-time variable like this:

```csharp
DateTime myDate=DateTime.Now; // result is like this: 8/2/2020 12:54:07 PM
```

and I want to get `myDate` variable like this

```csharp
DateTime getOnlyDate=myDate.Date;
```

and I want to get `myDate.Date;` with reflection
how can I get `Date` property value with reflection?
with reflection I do something like this:

```csharp
PropertyInfo myDate = typeof(DateTime).GetProperty("Date");
```

but I don`t know how can I request  `myDate.Date;` value with reflection.
thanks in advance

Comment: Add `myDate.GetValue(myDate)`;

Comment: @רועיאבידן: That's not going to work as-is, because `myDate` can't simultaneously be a `PropertyInfo` and a `DateTime`. I realize that's a problem in the OP's code, but it would be better not to propagate it into a comment.

Comment: You are right, didn't noticed he named both with the same name...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Once you've retrieved the `PropertyInfo`, you fetch the value with [`PropertyInfo.GetValue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.propertyinfo.getvalue?view=netcore-3.1), passing in "the thing you want to get the property from" (or `null` for a static property).

Here's an example:

```cs
using System;
using System.Reflection;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        DateTime utcNow = DateTime.UtcNow;
        
        PropertyInfo dateProperty = typeof(DateTime).GetProperty("Date");
        PropertyInfo utcNowProperty = typeof(DateTime).GetProperty("UtcNow");
        
        // For instance properties, pass in the instance you want to
        // fetch the value from. (In this case, the DateTime will be boxed.)
        DateTime date = (DateTime) dateProperty.GetValue(utcNow);
        Console.WriteLine($"Date: {date}");
        
        // For static properties, pass in null - there's no instance
        // involved.
        DateTime utcNowFromReflection = (DateTime) utcNowProperty.GetValue(null);
        Console.WriteLine($"Now: {utcNowFromReflection}");
    }
}
```